# IMPORTAR EVENTO ESPECÍFICO - PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um script onde faço um loop for e percorro cerca de 330 arquivos, com a finalidade de consolidar e aplicar um filtro no fim do processo. Como sou iniciante, fiz algumas tentativas mas sem sucesso.

Quero entender se há alguma forma de filtrar um evento específico de uma coluna do arquivo já na importação. Na prática, fazer o loop e consolidar apenas o evento a ser filtrado.

Não consigo fazer isso no fim, pois dá um erro de memória, pois os arquivos são pesados.

```
for x in tqdm(all_files):
    df = pd.read_csv(x, low_memory=False, encoding='latin1', sep=';')
    lt.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(lt, ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode filtrar utilizando o loc ou iloc do pandas

```
df = df.loc[['meu_campo'] == 'texto']
```

isso vai fazer com que aquele dataframe só tenha os dados referente ao filtro que adicionei

Para mais info sobre o método utilize a doc do pandas
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html